# Custom Graph API request on iPhone SDK

Tags: ios4, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to make a custom Graph API call using FBConnect?

For example,

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

With this call, I can see my own details.

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

With this I can see my friends.

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"FRIEND_ID/picture" andDelegate:self];
```

With this I can see a picture from a friend with id=FRIEND_ID.

Is there a possibility to make a custom Graph API call, to take id, picture, name and for example email, of all my facebook friends, in just one call?

Problem that I have is, when I call:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

In:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result;
```

I take the IDs of my friends, and then, in a for loop I want to do this:

```
[[self appDelegate].facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/picture",[[party.attendantsDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]] andDelegate:self];
```

Afterwards, in

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result;
```

I have:

```
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
    [party.attendantsPictures addObject:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:result]];
}
```

Problem is that pictures and names of my friends are all mixed up.

Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try NSRunLoop.

In my case, I wanna load user's name, status, profile picture at once. However, requestWithGraphPath and its delegate didload: result definitely only can handle each request at a time. So what I did is:

1/ Setup a tag number

2/ After each request, wait for the request to be completed, increase tag number by 1

So in my button action,

```
tagNo = 0;
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPathZero // For user's name
                       andDelegate:detailVC];
while ( tagNo == 0) && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPathOne // For user's status
                       andDelegate:detailVC];
while ( tagNo == 1) && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPathTwo // For user's profile picture
                       andDelegate:detailVC];
while ( tagNo == 2) && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
```

And in the delegate,

```
switch (tagNo) {
case 0:
    // Do something with result
    break;
case 1:
    // Do something with result
    break;
case 2:
    // Do something with result
    break;
default:
    break;
}
++tagNo;
```

I may not cover "Do something with result" here since it's in somewhere else in stackoverflow. This might not be the solution, but I found it approachable. Look for more contributions from others ;)

Comment: Hmmm, I've never used NSRunLoop. Could you give me a hint what it is? (Apple's Docs are little confusing...).

Comment: wow yr solution should be the correct one...what i did is just like request-wait until the request complete- then continue the next request

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I've never used NSRunLoop. Could you give me a hint what it is? (Apple's Docs are little confusing...).

In your case, I would do something like this:

```
NSString *fql = @"SELECT name, uid, pic_square, status FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fql, @"query", nil];
[facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

This way, you would get everything from the users, that you want.